# Test Class: How you you create a BrandTemplate for use in test class?

Tags: unit-test, email-template, campaign

I am currently working on testing related to sending HTML email messages using templates.  A template requires the BrandTemplateId to be assigned in order to be created.

1. I have tried to create a brand template in a test class, but receive the error "DML operation Insert not allowed on BrandTemplate".
2. I tried querying for any brand template  and get a null pointer exception.

If I can't create it and it doesn't exist, how do I create an HTML email template in a test class?

Comment: How are you querying for `BrandTemplate`s that generates a null pointer exception? In some quick testing, I'm seeing that both `BrandTemplate` and `EmailTemplate` are available in tests without using `SeeAllData=true`. I can also create additional `EmailTemplate` records in tests.

Comment: Hi Thomas, I have a TestDataFactory class where I create or prep all of the various data points for my test classes.  

In that class i have a single method to create a HTML Email template where, in the method, I query the brand template Id and assign it to the new html email template

"BrandTemplate tempId = [Select Id From BrandTemplate Limit 1];"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run into something you can't create in a unit test, you have two options:

1. Use `@isTest(SeeAllData=true)`
2. Use `Test.loadData()`

If at all possible, it's preferred to use the latter. From the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_load_data.htm):

> Using the Test.loadData method, you can populate data in your test methods without 
>   having to write many lines of code.
>
> Follow these steps:
>
> 1. Add the data in a .csv file.
> 2. Create a static resource for this file.
> 3. Call Test.loadData within your test method and passing it the sObject type token and the static resource name.

Comment: Are there entities for which `Test.loadData()` will work where regular `insert` DML fails? I'd have thought that either an entity can be inserted in test context or not.

Comment: I agree on avoiding 'SeeAllData=true'; I don't use it at all in any circumstance.  I will try the second option for loading data through a static resource and see if that works.  Thanks for the insight :)  I'll keep you posted.